# =IMPORTXTML() not working with dynamic date selection

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/fnoquote/" & A2 & "/2024-02-29/OPTSTK/CE/2700.00/true", "table", 6)
```

Is working fine in googlesheet to fetch data, but when i make date dynamic select from dropdown it stopped, and error `#N\A "Error Imported content is empty."`.

I Tried using single date with same date text format date are `2024-02-29`, `2024-03-28`, and `2024-04-25`.

This is my dynamic formula

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/india/fnoquote/" & A2 & "/" & TEXT('OI_ANALYSIS'!D1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "/OPTSTK/CE/2700.00/true", "table", 6)
```

there is a dropdown of those dates in sheet `OI_ANALYSIS CELL "D1"`.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Asking to correct formula .